# Mysql result loop for template engine

Tags: php, template-engine

What I am trying to do is to loop all the results with a use of very simple template engine.
The problem is that the script executes same result many times..
Right now there is 3 test works in the database(Test_1,Test_2,Test_3),
so basically the result looks like this now:

Test_3 Test localhost

Test_3 Test localhost

Test_3 Test localhost

```
$result = $pDatabase->query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //Loop Template (row)
        $works_row = new Template("works_row.tpl"); 
            //Changing all from $row[] to {}
            $rows[]=$row;
            $works_row->set("category",$row['category']);
            $works_row->set("name",$row['name']);
            $works_row->set("link",$row['link']);
    }
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $works_templates[] = $works_row;
    }
    $works_contents = Template::merge($works_templates);
    mysql_free_result($result);
    //Content part that calls all works
    $works_list  = new Template("works_block.tpl"); 
    $works_list->set("works_rows", $works_contents);
```

I don't really understand why doesn't it work right

Comment: You're most likely overwriting the items with `$works_row->set` each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,it works

```
    $result = $pDatabase->query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //Loop Template (row)
        $works_row = new Template("works_row.tpl"); 
            //Changing all from $row[] to {}
            $rows[]=$row;
            $works_row->set("category",$row['category']);
            $works_row->set("name",$row['name']);
            $works_row->set("link",$row['link']);
            $works_templates[] = $works_row;
    }

    $works_contents = Template::merge($works_templates);
    mysql_free_result($result);
    //Content part that calls all works
    $works_list  = new Template("works_block.tpl"); 
    $works_list->set("works_rows", $works_contents);
```